# Does it matter for the free() and delete[] if allocation was done on stack or heap?

Tags: c++, c, heap-memory, stack-memory

Free() knows how many bytes of memory to free but can delete[] do same thing? What if we allocate from stack instead of heap, do they work flawlessly with free() and delete[] ?
Last question: do we need to assign to NULL at the end?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * malloc2()
{
    char * m = (char *)malloc(100);
    //so malloc(10000000) cannot cause stack-overflow?
    //cast from void * to char *
    return m;
}

char * malloc3()
{
    static char m[100];
    //can [1000000] cause stack overflow?
    return m;
}

char * newX()
{
    char * output = new char[100];
    return output;
}

int main(){

    char * p = malloc2();
    //sizeof(p) gives 8 because this is on 64 bit OS/CPU
    free(p);
    //free() knows the size of p is 100.
    //Does it matter if this allocation from stack of malloc2()?
    p=NULL;

    char * q = malloc3();
    //again, sizeof(q) fives 8
    //is this allocation from stack of malloc3()?
    //I dont need to free because that was from an array declaration ?
    q=NULL;
    //then who  deletes that static array from the stack?


    char * r = malloc3();
    //now r and q point to same memory area ? 
    // then if I free q, I dont need to free r.
    r=NULL;

    char * s = newX();
    //allocation from stack again?
    //sizeof(s) gives 8, how can delete[] know its size?
    delete [] s;
    s=NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(p)` gives the size of `p`, that is, the amount of memory occupied by a `char*`; the result has nothing to do with how much memory may have been allocated by `malloc` or `new`.

Comment: Then the real length of array must be managed by programmer.

Comment: Yes. Which is why C++ has `std::string` and `std::vector`: they do the memory management for you.

Comment: malloc3() just return pointer to static array. Static variables not on the stack, they will be destroy on end the program.

Comment: Thank you ver much. I was going to make some serious JNI job but I fell in thought that should I allocate form function or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Neither `free` nor `delete` nor `delete []` work with stack-allocated memory.

The rule is actually ridiculously simple:

- Every `malloc` must be paired with exactly one `free`, and vice-versa.<sup>1</sup>
- Every `new` must be paired with exactly one `delete`, and vice-versa.
- Every `new []` must be paired with exactly one `delete []`, and vice-versa.

The end.

---

<sup>1</sup> Okay, I lied. `malloc`/`free` is harder, because there’s also `calloc` and `realloc`. Here’s the amended rule:

- Every `malloc` or `calloc` must be paired with exactly one call to `free` or `realloc`.
- Every `realloc` that does *not* free memory must be paired with exactly one call to `free` or `realloc`.
- (Vice-versa: Every `free` must belong to exactly one call made to `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`.)

In other words, `calloc` behaves like `malloc` (for the sake of memory allocation). `realloc` is an inclusive intermediate link of the `malloc` → `free` chain – it can replace both `malloc` and `free`, and it can be put in between such calls.

Comment: What if I do de allocation in a static way from function?

Comment: I like this, but the `malloc()` rule is a bit of an over-simplification — `calloc()` and (more particularly) `realloc()` complicate things.  Obviously, each `calloc()` should be associated with exactly one `free()`, just the same as `malloc()`.  But both are complicated by the 'complete memory manager in one function', namely `realloc()`.  _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_ You can use `realloc()` to change an allocation (in which case, you've freed the original allocation and should free the new allocation exactly once); you can use `realloc()` to free memory (in which case, you should not free it again); and you can use `realloc()` to allocate memory anew, in which case you need to free that.  So, a nuanced rule might be: _Every `malloc` or `calloc` must be paired with exactly one call to `free` or `realloc`; every call to `realloc` not freeing memory should be paired with exactly one call to `free` or `realloc`._

Comment: @Jonathan I thought about mentioning them and decided against it. Ah well.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I like the results, though.  If you'd have put all of the `malloc` details in the original rule, it would have made it overly verbose and complicated.  As a footnote, it fits in fine.

Comment: @KonradRudolph But you might add that the rules are commutative; e.g. that every `free` must correspond to exactly one `malloc`.  (I know, it seems obvious, but given the question, it's best to be overly explicit.)

Comment: @KonradRudolph For example.  At least, it's the clearest and most concise formulation I've seen to date (and my high school English teacher always said the good writing was clear and concise).

Answer (score 1):

You should *never* free or delete a stacked variable. They will automatically be destroyed when their stack frame returns. You may, only delete things allocated with new, and only free() things allocated by the malloc() family.

Comment: They're destroyed when they go out of scope; often that's the end of a function, but it doesn't have to be; variables defined inside a block are destroyed at the end of the block.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the last question: storing NULL in a pointer variable is only needed if your design calls for it; it's used to indicate that a pointer doesn't point to anything. Doing it here is just a waste of time, because `p` goes away at the end of the function:

```
void f() {
    char *p = new char[10];
    delete [] p;
    p = NULL;
}
```